# Assignment operation returns Object or Null in Java

Tags: java

While digging in ArrayList code I spotted this code fragment

```
  if ((lst = list) != null && (a = lst.elementData) != null) { ... }
```

Now I really don't know what this expression is called, talking about `(lst = list) != null`, and why it is used like this. It every assignment in java returns an assigned object or what?

Comment: Assignment is an *expression* whose value is the assigned value.

Comment: Instead of doing `lst = list;` before the if clause, you can do it in one go like this and save a line of code.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically assigning the value of *list* in *lst* and then doing other checks. The above code basically means

```
    lst = list;
    if ((lst != null && (a = lst.elementData) != null) { ... }
```

> why it is used like this

Probably just to save a line of code. It definitely reduces the readability a little bit.

Side note : This approach is very useful when you are doing something inside a loop.

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       // process the line.
    }
}
```

Here in the *while* loop the value of line keeps getting updated after each iteration of while loop.